# Page variant with selection rules: localhost

Tags: 7

after finishing a new theme, the dev and live servers are working great, but when I moved it all to my local desktop, the custom-pages are not showing up.

I have selection rules based on the url as we have about 6 sites of which the proper variant is served up according to the domain.

So, locally, nothing is showing. I'm guessing it's because of the selection rules. I can't add "localhost:8888" as a domain in the Domain Module we are using..it won't let me... so is there a way to override those rules when logged in as admin or some other one-shot way w/o removing all those selection rules per-page?

Comment: do you need those rules to work on you localhost? I was thinking maybe you just disable rules module all together.

Comment: hmm...I never thought about that. I'm only about 6 months into my Drupal experience so I didn't realize the rules models controlled that. I thought the rules mod was for rule sets, triggered rules etc. But I'll look into that, thanks

Comment: I think this might be more related to MAMP and the confusion of relative paths in Drupal. I eliminated the selection rule based on the domain altogether and it still doesn't preview..not sure if that's because it's looking for "localhost/" instead of "localhost/drupal/"...